# JGroups fetch IPAddess/bind_addr from a received Message

Tags: jgroups

I have a 3 node JGroups cluster working fine. Is there any way to retrieve `bind_addr` property from the other nodes via communication protocols?
 Essentially, I am trying to fetch IP address of the sender (on the receiver), or the IP address of the `dead` node in the changed `view`. Is there such a way?

Also, the class `Address`, contains `hostname`, can we configure this class to contain IP address (`bind_addr`) so that I can make use of?

`address instanceof IpAddress` this guy returns me `false` (as it is an instance of `UUID`).

On the current node:

`GMS gms = (GMS) stack.findProtocol(GMS.class);
logger.info("GMS.local address : "+gms.getLocalAddress());`

It returns me the `hostname` :(

I know working with `hostname` is recommended, but I would also like to retrieve the `bind_addr` in the message requests/cluster join/leave view changes.

Any help?

```
ProtocolStack stack = channel.getProtocolStack();
final TCP tcp = (TCP) stack.findProtocol(TCP.class);
channel.addAddressGenerator(new AddressGenerator() {
     public Address generateAddress() {
        ExtendedUUID retval = ExtendedUUID.randomUUID();
        retval.put("ip", tcp.getBindAddress().getAddress());
        return retval;
    }
});
channel.connect(clusterName);

byte[] ipAsByteArray =((ExtendedUUID)sourceAddress).get("ip");
String str=Util.bytesToString(ipAsByteArray);
```

This prints junk character :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding retrieving the IP, you should get hold of the transport protocol (`UDP` or `TCP`) and call `getBindAddress()`.

You can send this information via a custom address. For that you need to use `AddressGenerator`:

```
JChannel ch=new JChannel();
ch.addAddressGenerator(new AddressGenerator() {
    public Address generateAddress() {
        ExtendedUUID extendedAddress=ExtendedUUID.randomUUID();
            retval.put("ip", Util.stringToBytes(transportProtocol.getBindAddress().getAddress()));
            return extendedAddress;
        }
    });
ch.connect("my-cluster");
```

`ExtendedUUID` is basically a way to add additional payload to the address, but be aware that this payload is sent with all messages (keep it small!)

To retrieve the payload, you need to get the address from the message and do something like this:

```
Address sourceAddress = message.getSrc();
byte[] ipAsByteArray =((ExtendedUUID)sourceAddress).get("ip");
String str=Util.bytesToString(ipAsByteArray);
```

Comment: Hi Hardy, so this means for every `Message` in the `receive()` method, I can retrieve the IP address of the `sender`? Also, since I already have `hostname` through `JGroups`, I just want to augment the message to include the ip address, instead of creating a random UUID. Is there any way you could provide an example of retrieving this IP address in `receive` method? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but I am receiving some junk chars at output.. Looks like it's not reading the bytes at correct offset :|

Comment: Did you see that I added the use of `Util#stringToBytes` and `Util#bytesToString`. You can also check the existing code for the use of `ExtendedUUID`

Comment: `transportProtocol.getBindAddress().getAddress()` already provides `byte[]`. So we can't use `Util.stringToBytes`..

Comment: Actually it is an int, so you need to encode/decode accordingly.

Comment: Got it :) Actually putting bytes into buffer was causing problems while reading. `transportProtocol.getBindAddress().getAddress()`. Instead I not put `String ip` into the buffer and then convert it back `Util.bytesToString(ipAsByteArray)`, and I'm getting expected output :) Thanks for the hint!